# JS tab - paging or tab slider ala Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, user-controls, extjs

Not sure how what I am looking for is called so it's making it very hard to find relevant 
result.  So my question is really about finding the name for that type of control.

I am looking for a JS tab control plugin that would allow me to slide the tabs of a tab control the same way Firefox does it when you have many tabs open (with a **<** and **>** button).

I have found a few examples, the most similar to what I mean being this one but I can't use it to the commercial Ext JS license:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/tabs/tabs-adv.html

I've also found this one, which is still under development: 
http://www.seyfertdesign.com/jquery/examples.html

Does anyone know of any other or know what you would call that type of control so I can at least focus my search in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for the term "tab scrolling" ?

Comment: Yeah I suppose that's what it's called.  There's a lot of controls for desktop software... not so much in JS.  ExtJS definitely has one of the best, but its not free.  I've found one in DoJo maybe that will do thanks.